# What antivirus/internet security software now Kaspersky is off-limits?

Tags: malware, privacy, email, wifi, attacks

Now that the federal government has removed Kaspersky as a vendor, what software is recommended? I have used Kaspersky for 12 years, always with good results. Now, it seems they are a "back-channel" to the Kremlin. Any recommendations to replace Kaspersky internet security for the home user?

Answer (score 1):

The order to remove Kaspersky as a vendor only applies to government/DOD systems. You can use whatever solution you deem best for systems not under government control. Regardless of why you pick, realize that in making a choice you are trusting that vendor, and antivirus runs with admin privileges and can be a vector for attack.

Comment: I realize. I'm just at a loss as to what to use to replace Kaspersky. I won't use mcafee as I find it unreliable. Just looking for a good recommendation.

Comment: I personally recommend Avira. Have found it to be effective while ha Bing a low footprint on compute resources.